# VS - Office add-in doesn't load except if I stop the debugger

Tags: visual-studio, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, customtaskpane

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.8.3 to develop a Word Add-in.

I had no problem using it until today. I executed my solution but it appears that my taskpane doesn't load. I inspected it with DevTools and my taskpane is just entirely void (no HTML, CSS nor JS code, just nothing). The situation is the same for all others add-ins I downloaded. My manifest file loads properly though (the icons in my ribbon appear even though they cannot execute functions).

The weird thing is that my add-in actually works when I stop the debugger or detach all. When I do it, I can click on my "show taskpane" button and it loads properly. And if I just open Word without using VS, the add-ins I downloaded are also working normaly.

Did you already meet this problem? Do you have any guess how to resolve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab in the browser developer tools to see what is loaded or not?

Comment: This is a recent and known bug: [Addin stuck on Loading](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3889). It is being investigated by Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is the exact same problem. Looking forward for the resolution.

Comment: We think we've got a fix. It may take a few days for the fixed version to reach your M365 channel. Please retry.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that HTTPS protocol is used in both scenarios. The browser developer tools (especially the Network tab) or Fiddler can help you to figure out how everything is loaded.

There is a known issue, see https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3889 .

Comment: Thank you for you help! I looked in the network tab and it seems to the page is loading without end. It is the same bug as the one described by Rick. Hope the bug will be resolved soon.